What is a good statistical method to predict a choice among a bundle of choices?
I have a dataset which contains around 20000 observations and around 100 predictor variables. There are 4 dependent variables which denotes the 4 possible choices, where the variable takes on a value of "1" if the choice is selected and "0" if the choice is not selected. All predictor variables are alternative specific. The goal is to develop a model to best predict the choice among the set of choices.
The evaluation of the model is done by Logloss which is given by LogLoss formula.
I know I can use Multinomial choice and possibly Random Forest (correct me if im wrong). What are some good statistical models to go about this problem and what are some methods that I can use to lower my Logloss value.
Any experience with this kind of problem will be of great help. Thank You!
So far Ive tried multinomial but im looking for some other possible stastiscal models and methods.

Can more than one object be chosen by a person or is it always exclusive?

Its always exclusive

Then you do not really need 4 columns, you can put all the choices in one column with values 1 to 4 and do regular classification?
